# Dynamic insert the template to the base template

Tags: php, smarty

I want to dynamic insert the template to the base template:

I have three `tpl`, names `test.tpl`, `test01.tpl`, `test02.tpl`:

the code of `test.tpl`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{$title}</title>
    </head>

    {if $v eq 1}
        // there I want it to be test01.tpl, how to implements this?
    {elseif $v eq 2}
        // there I want it to be test02.tpl
    {/if}

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{$title}</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    {if $v eq 1}
        {include file='test01.tpl'}
    {elseif $v eq 2}
        {include file='test02.tpl'}
    {/if}

    </body>
</html>
```

{include} tags are used for including other templates in the current template.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{$title}</title>
    </head>
<body>

    {if $v eq 1}
        {include file="test01.tpl"}
    {elseif $v eq 2}
        {include file="test02.tpl"}
    {/if}

    </body>
</html>
```

This **{include}** tag include the targeted file when the condition get true.

Answer (score 0):

Use **include** function

```
{include file='test01.tpl'}
```

https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.include.tpl